# Listview not getting updated Image-URL after Updating record in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

After updating the image field the listview data for image which is pointing to a URL is not getting refreshed.

In XAML code

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" HasUnevenRows="True" Margin="5" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
         ItemTapped="MyListView_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Image HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageURL}" />
                        <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="Default" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                            <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Default" Text="{Binding Weight, StringFormat='{0}'}"></Label>
                            <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Default" Text="{Binding Unit, StringFormat='{0}'}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="Default" Text="{Binding Amount}"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Code behind

```
List<Product> allData = new List<Product>();
// CALL FOR WEB API AND BELOW RESPONSE

var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

allData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(result);

MyListView.ItemsSource = null;
MyListView.ItemsSource = allData;
```

when i select a record for edit the image field, i save it on the server and image gets replaced. now when i refresh the list as per above code, it does not list the updated record. it gets refreshed after i reinstall the app.

Comment: are you positive that the new url is returned when you call the API again?

Comment: Please add a break point in `allData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(result);` line, then check the record if you can get the new data.

Comment: Yes. Separately if I open same url on Browser it opens as new one. And reinstalling the app gives the updated image

Comment: I debugged the same, inside the List the Object ImageURL have url which has updated Image. But while Binding it displays old image only.

Comment: Before execute `allData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(result);`, please execute the `allData.Clear();` then ` List<Product> NewData =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(result);`, Use foreach to traverse the entire NewData，Use `allData.Add(item) ` to add every new record to the `allData`. In the end, set `MyListView.ItemsSource = null; MyListView.ItemsSource = allData;`

Comment: this sounds like a caching issue - you might want to play with the caching options of the ListView

Comment: @Jason, Leon I tried to clear the allData variable and ItemSource to null. Then also its getting from cache. Also when I click on specific Row in Listview it redirects me to Another Screen with Details including Image, here Image is coming correct. So its proved that Listview is getting cahced Images.
 I read from one article that it resides in cache for 24 Hrs or so and expire automatically. Can we check whether there is a way to Disable the Cache for ListView.

Comment: that is specifically what I suggested - "you might want to play with the caching options of the ListView".  Read the docs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#caching-strategy